# ElasticSearch 5 field name compression

Tags: elasticsearch

We will have a almost 5 billion documents to index ES5.x .  I didn't find information about the field name compression.

we are using  "ca" instead of "created_at" in our previous system to save space.

Do we need to keep field name smaller in ES5.x  or it is already compressed somehow ?

Thx

Comment: I would be surprised to hear that field names are stored all over for each document. If you have a new field in every document, this may make sense (if this is supported at all) but if all documents have the same mapping type, there should be no need need to optimize the field names.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a MongoDB background (where this used to be / is an issue)?

[Quoting](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Field-name-size-and-index-size-td553525.html) one of the Lucene core contributors, since the storage is Lucene's job:

> There is a single file per segment (*.fnm) that resolves the field
>   names into integer IDs, then the rest of the index uses these integer
>   IDs.  So only that file, which holds one copy of the string name of
>   each field, will be bigger.

Thus the effect of shortening field names will be absolutely minimal. However, depending on your mapping, the storage in Elasticsearch can be smaller or bigger than the JSON source, but this depends on the mapping and how well your data can be [compressed in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/store-compression-in-lucene-and-elasticsearch).

Comment: Yes..  we have WWIII  wit mongodb :)  if ES shortening the field name thats fantastic.  thanks..